# How to select text in DTAttributedTextView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using `DTCoreText` `DTAttributedTextView` in my app to highlight the urls in my text. My other criteria is to be able to select by tapping and holding similar to `UITextView`. However, `DTAttributedTextView` doesn't seem to to use a `UITextView` as a placeholder. Anybody has an idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature that's only available via the paid version of DTCoreText.

[from the github page](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)

> This is useful for drawing simple rich text like any HTML document without having to use a UIWebView. For text selection and highlighting (as you might need for an Editor or Reader) there is the commercial DTRichTextEditor component which can be purchased in the Cocoanetics Parts Store.